# `KeyboardEvent.key` not capitalised when holding `Meta` and `Shift` on Mac OS X

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

On Mac OS X, in both Chrome and Firefox, when the Command (i.e. Meta) key is held, the Shift key does not seem to affect capitalisation of the `KeyboardEvent.key` property. This can be tested by logging `event.key` in a `keydown` event:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", event => console.log(event.key));
```

Holding Command-Shift-Z produces `"z"`. Holding other modifiers, like Control-Shift-Z produce `"Z"` as expected. In other operating systems, this does not seem to occur: holding Shift will always make a letter capitalised.

Is this expected behaviour? If is, what's the reason behind it? I can't find any mention of it in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-key/). If this isn't expected, what might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Unable to reproduce meta key effects under Windows because it [doesn't have one key](https://askubuntu.com/a/19565/1555883). Although some may call the windows logo key the "META", logo key presses are consumed by Windows without being sent to the browser. Apparently there is an option in mac terminal profile settings to configure Meta key emulation, but I don't know if it is related to the post.